# Do I need to use package json lock file when all of them are static?

Tags: javascript, npm

Let's say all of the dependencies in my `package.json` are static. I'm not using the tilde or the caret.

Will anything be different in this case if I do or don't have a `package.lock`?

Comment: All of your dependencies are static, but your dependencies' dependencies might not be. So without a `package-lock.json`, you cannot be 100% sure your dependency tree will be exactly the same when installed at different times.

Comment: Thanks, make sense.